# Java console error message while using test harness

Tags: java

I was trying to do the java tutorial on regexes and it had a test harness. I copied the code and tried to run it.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexTestHarness {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console console = System.console();

        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (true) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(console.readLine("Enter input string to search: "));
            boolean found = false;

            while (matcher.find()) {
                console.format("I found the text" +
                " \"%s\" starting at " +
                "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                matcher.group(),
                matcher.start(),
                matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }

            if (!found) {
                console.format("No match found.%n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error message on my console

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
>   No console.

It's importing "console" and displaying the error on my console. So I am not sure why it is not creating a console.

The page can be found at: [JAVA test Harness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html)

Comment: Are you running your application under eclipse? If so use java.util.Scanner because System.console() return null (eclipse bug :https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the code using the Scanner adapted for a Java compilator 
(eclipse for me):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

/*
 * Test for regular expressions - Test Harness
 * List of commands and more info:
 * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html
*/
public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.printf("%nEnter your regex: ");
            Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(in.nextLine());

            System.out.printf("Enter input string to search: ");
            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(in.nextLine());

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.printf("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),
                    matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
                System.out.printf("No match found.%n");
            }
            in.close();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following. It is also having while loop, so you can practice your regex effortlessly.

```
package regex;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.printf("%nEnter your regex: ");
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(in.nextLine());

            System.out.printf("Enter input string to search: ");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(in.nextLine());

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.printf("I found the text" + " \"%s\" starting at " + "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                        matcher.group(), matcher.start(), matcher.end());
                found = true;
            }
            if (!found) {
                System.out.printf("No match found.%n");
            }
            // in.close();
        }
    }
}
```